# Android - Blogger (Best method of authentication - ClientLogin, etc)

Tags: java, android, http, blogger

I have been directed here by someone from the Google Blogger Developer group.  My question is basically, what is the best way to authenticate with the Blogger service within Android.

Initially I used HTTPURLConnect in Java and sent requests and received responses, this worked fine when the correct username and password were provided, however, when an incorrect password was supplied rather than being given the response `Error=BadAuthentication`, Java threw a `FileNotFoundException` for https:// www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin.  My plan obviously being to parse the response given by Google (according to this list: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html#Response)

The second attempt I have used this library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

However, here I get the following error (regardless of credentials):

```
02-11 16:57:46.515: INFO/dalvikvm(294): Could not find method 
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.getCurrentToken, referenced from 
method 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.JsonCParser.parserForResponse
```

If anyone could provide any insight at all into these errors OR a better way to implement an application where user on Android can login and then read/view/create/edit blog posts on Blogger using the GData API, I'd be hugely grateful.

Thanks,

Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the google-api-client-1.2.2-alpha.jar (or the version of the API you are using) to the Build Path:

If you're using Eclipse:
Right Click on your project and go to Properties.
Go to Java Build Path in the left bar. Choose the Libraries tab and then "Add External Jar...".
Add the google-api-client-1.2.2-alpha.jar file and try to run again.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have already done this which is why I am confused by the error - see this screenshot:

http://i52.tinypic.com/2ps0x8l.png

Any ideas?

Comment: I analysed the google-api-client-1.2.2-alpha.jar. It doesn't contain the jackson library: get it here: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.2/jackson-all-1.7.2.jar . And the JsonCParser class uses it. Add it to the Build Path also.

Comment: Thanks!  That's really helpful.  It no longer gives the error now.